# How to get rid of the program name bar at the top of the application?

Tags: android

i would like to get rid of the defualt grey bar which apears at the top of my application.
I just can't seem to find the attribute or setting to do so.
how can this be achived?
thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`, either for this specific `<activity>` element in your manifest, or for the whole `<application>` element if you want it gone for all of them. Here's a [FAQ entry](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#configurewindowproperties) about it.

Comment: Remember that this also disables the Action Bar.

Comment: +1 for specifying that you can also disable it per activity. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

I tried the manifest method but for some reason it wasn't working.
However using the .java method as described [here](http://kandroid.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/remove-title-bar-from-your-app/) worked.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: This worked for my purpose as I have View Pagers and Fragment Activities.

Answer (score 3):

Open app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good article why you should avoid removing the title bar from an app by Googler Reto Meier:
http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/07/how-to-display-android-status-bar-in.html

Read and rethink if you really need to remove the title bar from your app.

Comment: I am just removing the Title bar not the notification bar. (the one that says the name of the application)