# Android Canvas Area is not full screen. How to set canvas area?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

[image]

Hello.
I draw a rectangle overlay on Android Canvas.

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000, paint);
```

That is my code. I set start point is (0,0) that is (left, top) coordinate.
But (0,0) is not on a left-top end point of full screen.
No matter how width and height are big, canvas cannot cover full screen also.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fullscreen view, use the `setContentView(canvas)` call. That sets the full canvas view as the layout.

Comment: I make a class that extends View. And I make a Service class that uses the View object via WindowManager. TTTTT So I can call setContentView method because of not Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that by default, XML uses a thing called Titlebar, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526864/4879856). Along with removing the Titlebar, you can set your activity to full-screen and also remove the status-bar by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547124/4879856).

Make sure that your activity imports from `Activity` rather than `ActionBarActivity`.

Also, it is better to avoid using actual numbers when setting a position or a size, and especially when the goal is to cover the entire screen. You can get the width and height of the screen by using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` accordingly:

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

**Make sure to use these methods only in or after the** `onDraw` **method was called**, else their values will be equal to 0 since the canvas was not yet initialized.

Comment: How to calculate getWidth() and getHeight() ?